# How to use a function as an argument of another function in php using callable pseudo type?

Tags: php, function, echo, callable

I just read about callable type from php.net and assume using `callable` keyword should allow passing the function as the argument to another function. But, I am getting warning. Here's what I've tried:

```
<?php

function helloWorld()
{
   echo 'Hello World!';
}
function handle(callable $fn)
{
   $fn(); 
}

handle(helloWorld); // Outputs: Hello World!

?>
```

But, I get sometimes following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

and sometimes

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant helloWorld - assumed 'helloWorld' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\Projects\Sandbox\myphp on line 12
```

Q1. Why does php expect `helloWorld` to be a variable, where it's already been explicitly defined as a function.
Q2. Apparently, removing the keyword `callable` in the function definition makes no difference. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the argument in quotes, like this:

```
handle('helloWorld');
```

rather than

```
handle(helloWorld);
```

The [PHP Docs for `callable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) state that "A PHP function is passed by its name as a string".